# Postgesql: count contains tags for items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains **items** and **tags**.
How to make a request that will show tags and the number of identical **tags** to my **item**.

```
CREATE TABLE items_tags_sets (
uit_set_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
item_id varchar,
tag varchar
);

insert into items_tags_sets values('uid1', 'it1', 'tag_test1');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid2', 'it2', 'tag_test1');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid3', 'it3', 'tag_test2');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid4', 'it4', 'tag_test2');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid5', 'it1', 'tag_test3');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid6', 'it2', 'tag_test3');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid7', 'it3', 'tag_test4');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid8', 'it4', 'tag_test4');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid9', 'it1', 'tag_test5');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid10', 'it2', 'tag_test5');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid11', 'it1', 'tag_test1');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid12', 'it1', 'tag_test1');
insert into items_tags_sets values('uid13', 'it1', 'tag_test3');
----------------------------------
-- 28062020
select
    items_tags_sets.uit_set_id,
    items_tags_sets.item_id,
    items_tags_sets.tag,
  count(distinct items_tags_sets.tag) as tags_count
  
from items_tags_sets
where 
items_tags_sets.item_id = 'it1'
group by items_tags_sets.uit_set_id, items_tags_sets.tag;
```

I need a result like this:

```
-----------------------
| it1 | tag_test1 | 3 |
| it1 | tag_test3 | 2 |
| it1 | tag_test5 | 1 |
-----------------------
```

Link to code: https://rextester.com/CTMOQ42435

Comment: I don't see where 3/2/1 come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by item_id, tag`:

```
select
  item_id,
  tag,
  count(*) as tags_count
from items_tags_sets
where item_id = 'it1'
group by item_id, tag;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kxJZJ48RF972Jz4b2EnggE/1).
Results:

```
| item_id | tag       | tags_count |
| ------- | --------- | ---------- |
| it1     | tag_test1 | 3          |
| it1     | tag_test3 | 2          |
| it1     | tag_test5 | 1          |
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you want a self join and aggregation:

```
select its_1.item_id, its_1.tag, count(distinct its.item_id) as cnt
from items_tags_sets its_1 left join
     items_tags_sets its
     on its_1.tag = its.tag 
where its_1.item_id = 'it1'
group by its_1.item_id, its_1.tag
order by cnt desc;
```

However, this returns 2/2/2 rather than 3/2/1.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=93e35ea6a3640fd47726042dd17f9d4f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude the column which are not being used in group by clause in case you are not using any aggregate function on that.

```
select
item_id,
tag,
count(tag) as tags_count
  
from items_tags_sets
where 
item_id = 'it1'
group by item_id, tag;
```

OUTPUT----------

```
item_id tag tags_count
it1 tag_test1   3
it1 tag_test3   2
it1 tag_test5   1
```